# Running a Matlab standalone application on Raspberry pi

Tags: c, matlab, raspberry-pi, matlab-compiler, matlab-coder

i have make a standalone application with Matlab Compiler. Now i want to run this application on my Raspberry pi (model 3b). Is this possible? This application is just a GUI to calculate some values.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Comment: I've seen [Makerzone](http://makerzone.mathworks.com/) advertising MATLAB with Raspberry pi, but I've not looked into it.